# Buscar un dato especifico dentro de un "vector"

Tags: java, netbeans, arraylist, netbeans-8.2, vectores

Tengo un programa en el cual ingreso 4 nombres con sus respectivos 4 valores de factura, quisiera conocer la posición especifica de un dato, al realizar el código no estoy 100% seguro si va a funcionar y además como debería de comparar los valores tipo String

bad operand types for binary operator

EL error lo señalo con flechas es

```
    while(i<4 &&  vnombre[i]<buscar_nombre[i])  
       
       {
        i++;
        }
```

Este es todo el programa por completo

```
    
package buscar_vector;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class Buscar_vector {

   
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader datos= new  BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String vnombre[]=new String[4];
        String vfactura[]=new String[4];
        String buscar_nombre[]=new String[4];
        String buscar_factura[]=new String[4];
        
        int i; 
        
        
        //llena el vector
        do{
            
        
        for(i=0;i<vnombre.length;i++)
        {
         
         vnombre[i]=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Nombre: "+"\n corresponde a  la casilla N."+i);
         vfactura[i]=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Valor de la factura"+"\n Corresponde a la casilla no. "+i+" de:  "+vnombre[i]);
         
        }
        
        buscar_nombre[i] =JOptionPane.showInputDialog("\n Buscar nombre "+buscar_nombre[i]);
        //sacar la informacion
        
        for(i=0;i<vnombre.length;i++)
        {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," corresponde a  la casilla N."+i+"\n NOMBRE: "+vnombre[i]+"\n Valor factura: "+vfactura[i]);    
        }
        
        
        }
        while(i<4 &&  vnombre[i]<buscar_nombre[i]){
        i++;
        }
                    
        
        if(i==4){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"\n Nombre no encontrado");
        }else{
              if(vnombre[i] == buscar_nombre[i]){
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"\n Nombre encontrado en la posicion"+i);
              } 
        }
        }
    }
```

Es asi como funciona y el error que aparece es bad operand types for binary operator

Comment: Para comparar Strings en Java se usa el método `equals();`

Comment: Y la manera correcta sería buscar_nombre

Comment: If(buscar_nombre.equals(vnombre [i]){ JOptionPane.showMessageDialog("el nombre es: ");}   no logro seleccionar un solo nombre de la lista de nombres del vector

Comment: Otro problema que tienes es que comparas `vnombre[i]<buscar_nombre[i]`, no puedes hacer eso ya que ambos son Strings, por eso tienes el error: bad operand types for binary operator

Comment: Para responder se necesitaría

Comment: Para buscar e imprimir el dato se necesitaría.         for(i=0;i<vnombre.length;i++){                                  if(buscar.equalsIgnoreCase(vnombre[i]){            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"el dato buscado es:"+vnombre[i]+"factura :"+vfactura[i]); }}